# Agora.io Integrating on page sales options

Tags: agora.io

I am after creating several purchase options on my website that will allow customers to buy options with a set amount of minutes. As an example one option is my education package which is for 3000 minutes a month at a monthly cost. I’m total there will be about 7 different options including a pay as you go option so people pay per minute for what they use.

All my developers seem to keep struggling doing this. We are trying to use Agora.io. Can anyone help guide myself and my developers in the correct direction. Or maybe it is not do-able.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It is great to hear that you are trying out Agora. We provide easy-to-implement and high-quality video and audio SDKs. To answer your question, I am not entirely sure about the details of your purchase plan. But here is Agora's pricing and how we calculate the minutes.

Every month, you will get 10,000 mins for free. The pricing for the extra mins is:

- Voice: $0.99 per 1000 min
- Video: $3.99 per 1000 min (less than 720p)
- Video: $14.99 per 1000 min (HD)

For more information, you can check out this pricing page: https://www.agora.io/en/pricing/

Agora calculates mins by the upstream mins and the downstream mins. For example, if you are doing broadcasting. You have 4 broadcaster hosts, 50 audiences, and a streaming length of 10 mins.

Your Agora mins will be: [host side upstream and downstream] (3 * 4 + 4) * 10min + [audience side downstream. audience only need to have downstream] 50 * 4 * 10min = 2160 mins

Hope it helps with your purchase option decision.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have looked into the pricing and your showing what i have seen. I have heard back off sales and it looks like i may have to find one of their partners to achieve what i am after. I may not be able to use Agora which is a shame because i dont think it will allow me to make several options for people to purchase every month on my site.